# Problem in compiling a java program on Mac terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, compilation

I downloaded JDK and have also set up the JAVA_HOME environment, but something just doesn't seem right because whenever I write my first program, save it, and then give the command for compilation, terminal shows an error.

I have copy-pasted lines from my terminal for reference:

```
gaurii@Gauriis-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd Desktop
gaurii@Gauriis-MacBook-Pro Desktop % touch helloworld.java
```

`(The file appeared on my desktop)`

```
gaurii@Gauriis-MacBook-Pro Desktop % vi helloworld.java
```

`(I wrote the code and saved it)`

```
gaurii@Gauriis-MacBook-Pro Desktop % ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
gaurii@Gauriis-MacBook-Pro Desktop % javac helloworld.java
error: file not found: helloworld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

`And this is what I get when I write the help command -`

```
gaurii@Gauriis-MacBook-Pro Desktop % --help
zsh: command not found: --help
```

{Please guide me as I have tried a lot and still not getting the result, also, being new to terminal is making it harder}

Comment: Looks like a macos problem, not a java problem. You're having permission problems in your desktop folder.

Comment: Also, `--help` is not a command, so don't expect it to work.

Comment: As soon as you saw the `ls: .: Operation not permitted` message, you should not have expected _anything_ you do in the Desktop directory to work. Fix that problem first. For example, see https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Comment: `echo 'public class HelloWorld {}' > HelloWorld.java;javac HelloWorld.java` Now it's compiled. Edit with `vi` and recompile

Comment: You don't need `touch`  and can use `vi` right away. Since it didn't give an error though, you don't have a problem writing to Desktop

Comment: It looks like you can _write_ to the Desktop but not read from it (or list its contents). Hence, the `javac` command was unable to find the file, even though it exists. Once you fix the MacOS permissions, as shown in the earlier link, you should be able to compile the file.

Comment: What does `sudo ls -ld .` give?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to put your Java source files into such a specific directory? I suggest that you put it into some project directory. If you WANT to see an icon for it on the desktop, create a symlink in ~/Desktop.